# How to dynamically output value in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have created a model in which turtles are born and die based on certain parameters. But at any given point, lets say no more than 20 turtles are alive.

With the birth and death of each new turtle, the turtle label keeps increasing incrementally i.e. initially there are 5 turtles, the 3rd turtle dies and in the next tick a new turtle is born. The new turtle born has a label of 6 and thus old labels are retired and replaced with the next label.

If i want to output a metric associated with the turtles into the monitor, is there a way to dynamically ensure that. i.e. since there can't be more than 20 turtles at any tick, can i make netlogo display the turtle metric along with the turtle label automatically. Otherwise i will have to create 100's of monitors and then code with [metric] or turtle 0.....[metric] of turtle n which is not practical.

Comment: When you say "label", what you really mean is the `who` number of the turtle. Turtles in NetLogo do have a `label` variable, but that's a different concept.

Comment: Yes i  mean the who number, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a separate monitor for each turtle, you can do something like this:
[image]

Using `[ metric ] of item 0 sort turtles` instead of `[ metric ] of turtle 0` (and so on) will insure that you're not depending on the `who` numbers of the turtles, you're only depending on their position in the sorted list of turtles.

Note that this would be *very* inefficient, because each monitor would keep re-sorting the turtles over and over again.

That being said, I think there would be many different, better ways to approach this. Here is one fully working example:

```
turtles-own [ metric ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20 [ set metric random 10 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask n-of 5 turtles [ die ]
  create-turtles 5 [ set metric random 10 ]
  tick
end

to-report info [ the-turtle ]
  ; format this however you want:
  report [ (word who ": " metric ", ") ] of the-turtle
end
```

And then, in a monitor, put:

```
map info sort turtles
```

Which will give you something like:

[image]

If [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) is obscure to you, you may want to check its dictionary entry. The basic idea is that we build a new list of strings by applying the `info` reporter to each element of our list of turtles.

I used a monitor in the example because that's what you were talking about in your question, but for displaying information about multiple turtles like this, maybe a plot or the output widget would be more appropriate. In any case, you could use a similar approach, with either [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) or [`foreach`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach).

One word of advice in closing. Your question shows that you're probably aware of that already, but any time you're tempted to refer to turtles by their `who` number (i.e., `turtle 0`, `turtle 1`, `turtle 27`, etc.), it probably means you're on the wrong track. NetLogo is built to manipulate agentsets and lists; take advantage of that. And when you do need to refer to a particular turtle, use a reference to that turtle (e.g., `the-turtle` in the example above), never (or almost never) its `who` number.

Comment: Hello thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. Thanks for the advice, i do agree with you, as a matter of fact i am not even interested in the individual turtles since they keep dying and new ones are born. Each turtle in my model falls under 5 categories, say A..E  I am interested in the metric aggregated at this level i.e. [metric] of A and so forth. For that i did create a list but this is something i am being forced to do and don't really have a choice on the matter unfortunately